# Terser setting to minify/hoist the this variable and properties

Tags: javascript, terser

Is there any way for terser to minify/hoist the `this` variable so it does not appear repeated as often in the bundle?

Example code:

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(handler) {
        this.handler = handler;

        this.handler.on('method1', this.method1.bind(this));
        this.handler.on('method2', this.method2.bind(this));
        this.handler.on('method3', this.method3.bind(this));
        this.handler.on('method4', this.method4.bind(this));
        this.handler.on('method5', this.method5.bind(this));
        this.handler.on('method6', this.method6.bind(this));
        this.handler.on('method7', this.method7.bind(this));
        this.handler.on('method8', this.method8.bind(this));
        this.handler.on('method9', this.method9.bind(this));
        this.handler.on('method10', this.method10.bind(this));
    }

    method1() {}
    method2() {}
    method3() {}
    method4() {}
    method5() {}
    method6() {}
    method7() {}
    method8() {}
    method9() {}
    method10() {}
}

new MyClass();
```

Ideally, I would love terser to be smart to detect repeated usages of this and hoist the reference. Something like this:

```js
const a = this;
a.handler.on('method1', a.method1.bind(a));
// ...
```

What about the `handler` property? Perhaps it can be also smart and compress further to:

```js
const a = this;
const h = a.handler; // (actually, `handler` because it's argument var)
h.on('method1', a.method1.bind(a));
// ...
```

Comment: I've tested terser output using its playground: https://try.terser.org/

Comment: The first: yes it might do that, although repeating `this` will hardly have any effect on the size of gzipped bundle, it might even worsen it so it's probably not smart. The second: no, it can't do that, this changes the semantics of the code. You'll have to do this in the code yourself (just refer to `handler.on(…)` instead of `this.handler.on(…)`).